# mutate at - count the number of times specified columns exceed some specified number,

Tags: apply, dplyr

This is a real-world problem but I am describing the reproducible iris example:

I want to count, for each row, the number of times columns with column names containing "Sepal", exceed a number 5. I want to assign the new result in a new column. I want to use dplyr for this task. My attempt is the following:

`iris %>% mutate_at(vars(contains("Sepal")),list(greater_than_5=~apply(.,1,function(x) sum(x>5))))`

However, I get an error:

````
  dim(X) must have a positive length```

Any ideas?
````

Comment: It will be the same number for all rows, since the column names are static for each row. `mutate_at` tries to mutate at each column, so that's not what you want. If that IS actually what you want, then you'd want something like: `iris %>% mutate(count = ifelse(sum(str_detect(names(.),title_word)) > min_to_count, sum(str_detect(names(.),title_word)), NA_real_))`. However, I suggest `pivoting_longer` and will write up and answer using that technique in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing an example of what you want your output to look like and/or explanation, it's hard to determine exactly what you're looking for, so here are two possible solutions (including the one I mentioned in the comments above). The first I think will be unsatisfactory since your count will be the same for all rows because the tibble is static. The second uses R's bread and butter--a tidy (long form) data structure--to count only those "columns" that have non-NA values. There we add a row id that we can group by later, pivot to a tidy form, filter out NAs, count the number of column/parameter names that contain your word of interest, and the pivot back to your original wide form tibble. We need to wrap the value column in list form since the datatypes differ across the different parameters--you could convert everything to a character, of course, but you'll see this lets us recover the original types after unnesting.

```
library(tidyverse)

min_to_count = 5
title_word = "Sepal"

iris %>% mutate(name_count = ifelse(sum(str_detect(names(.),title_word)) > min_to_count, sum(str_detect(names(.),title_word)), NA_real_))

iris %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -id,
    names_to = "parameter", values_to = "value",
    values_ptypes = list(value = list())
  ) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(unlist(value))) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    name_count = ifelse(
      sum(str_detect(parameter, title_word)) > min_to_count,
      sum(str_detect(parameter, title_word)), NA_real_
    )
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = "parameter", values_from = "value"
  ) %>% 
  unnest_legacy()
```

Comment: Cool thanks. I obviously thought that mutate_at works differently. Here is an easy solution with mutate:
`sum_rows=function(df,word="Sepal")
{ 
  df = df %>% select_at(vars(contains(word))) 
  return(apply(df,1,function(x) sum(x>5)))
}
iris %>% mutate(name_count=sum_rows(.))
`

I couldn't update my tidyverse version so I adopted your solution to use gather and spread. Could you compare this long solution to the simple one I proposed - is there any efficiency advantage over your solution - it seems like a lot of data wrangling for a simple operation..

Comment: Here is the adoptation of your solution: `iris %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>% gather(-id,key = "parameter", value = "value") %>% filter(!is.na(value))%>%
  group_by(id) %>% filter(str_detect(parameter,"Sepal")) %>% mutate(name_count=sum(value>5)) %>% spread(key="parameter",value="value")
`

Comment: Your sum rows function is essentially the same as the first solution (line #4). The key reason you'd need to bother with gathering/spreading (or pivoting if you had the update) is if you wanted to determine whether there was data in the row in the columns with a particular name--which is what I assumed the purpose of this was. Otherwise, there's no reason to do anything other than run `stringr::str_detect` on everything (and `ifelse` if you needed the > 5 times).

Comment: Also, I don't think you mean to do `name_count = sum(value>5)`, right? That would count columns where the value is greater than 5, which is not what you asked for. 

I haven't run your new code, but does it automatically wrap your values in a list? That's another key advantage of pivoting, unless I missed where gather does that by default.